# Issues automating printer driver update (printer settings) and printer preferences in Win7, using a PS,cmd,vbs,etc script?

Tags: powershell, printing, cmd, wmi, wmic

WMI can do it, but I have an issue, PCs are on, but logged off. If I try to run:

```
wmic /node:%strIP% printer where DeviceID="lp1" set DriverName="Lexmark Universal v2"
```

It fails with a message about a "generic failure". I RDP in and then run the same command from my end, and it works.  Powershell version I am using is older, so it does not have some of the printer cmdlets, and updating PS is currently out of the question.  Is there a way to remotely log someone in, without actually having to RDP in? Via PS, cmd, PSEXEC, etc?

The other avenue I've taken is using regedit, but I'm hitting some hicups with that, namely that I cannot figure out what to copy. In regedit, I can change the drivername and the setting that enable duplex and tray2 (in printer settings), but I cannot figure how to change the settings in printer preferences for printing double sided and doing so along the long edge.

What I did to figure out what to change, I did a find on the printer name in regedit as a data value and exported the keys before changing the settings. Then I exported it again AFTER changing the settings.  I then used `fc /c /a /u before.reg after.reg` to get the changes.  I chopped up the .reg to include only the changed values.  Running the .reg seems to change everything, but the print both sides, along the long edge settings. It is a lexmark printer, so I am wondering if maybe preferences for it are stored elsewhere.

This is my most up to date PS1 script. I've commented out some lines as I tried different ways of doing things:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Str = Read-Host "Please select a site ID [###] "
$PC = Read-Host "Please select a PC number [##] "

Clear-Host
$PCNm = "$Str-CCPC-$PC"

function Test-PsRemoting
{
    try
    {
        $errorActionPreference = "Stop"
        $result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PCNm { 1 }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Verbose $_
        return $false
    }

    if($result -ne 1)
    {
        Write-Verbose "Remoting to $PCNm returned an unexpected result."
        return $false
    }

    $true   
} 

If(!(Test-PsRemoting)){
    PSEXEC \\$PCNm powershell Enable-PSRemoting -force 2>&1 >nul
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "Enabled PsRemoting"
}else{Write-Host "PsRemoting already enabled"}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PCNm -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
    #$lp1 = Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT * from Win32_Printer Where DeviceID='lp1'"
    $lp1 = Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer | ?{$_.name -eq "lp1"}
    $lp1.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = $true
    $lp1.DriverName = "Lexmark Universal v2"
    $lp1R = $lp1.Put()
    #$lp2 = Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT * from Win32_Printer Where DeviceID='lp2'"
    $lp2 = Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer | ?{$_.name -eq "lp2"}
    $lp2.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = $true
    $lp2.DriverName = "Lexmark Universal v2"
    $lp2R = $lp2.Put()
}

#$lp1 = Get-WMIObject -Impersonation Delegate -Authentication Call -Credential $Cred -ComputerName $PCNm -Query "SELECT * from Win32_Printer Where DeviceID='lp1'"
#$lp1.DriverName = "Lexmark Universal v2"
#$lp1.Put()
```

No matter which way I try it, invoke-command, or get-wmiobject, I get:

```
Exception calling "Put" with "0" argument(s): "Generic failure "
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
    + PSComputerName        : 150-CCPC-02
```

Comment: Not really a programming question, or scripting specific, you should flag for a mod to migrate this to [sf].

Comment: I edited the question. The piece of code is part of a cmd script, though I did try PS1 as well, but being that I am using an older version, some of the cmdlets that exist now for win8, are unusable for me. This is why I'm using `%strIP%` as that is requested from the user earlier.

Comment: Sure...but the problem is about to how to make the OS do something when a user is logged off, just because that happens to be in a script doesn't make it more programmery. Honest, you're more likely to get better set of eyes i.e. professional sysadmins who know wmic etc on [SF] or [SU].

Comment: have you tried `invoke-command` via PSRemoting?

Comment: I guess you should improve the `where` clause of your `wmic` query as `lpt1` has to to with `PortName` property rather than the `DeviceID` property. Try `wmic /node:%strIP% printer get /value` for a _human readable_ output

Comment: Despite of my previous comment: right **syntax** should be as `where "DeviceID='lp1'"` instead of `where DeviceID="lp1"`

Comment: @ssaviers Try WMI via a PS invoke-command?  I'll have to wait for them to log off to try that, I don't think it will work since from what I am reading is that WMI needs a user on to run the service.

Comment: @JosefZ That `/value` tag is great, and yes, more readable than wrapped output.  I'll use that to compare on contrast the before and after and see if the setting I want changed reside there. I know technically anything there should be in the registry, but everything in the registry need not be there, so I think some of the setting may be Lexmark specific and since the registry has a printerdata entry as hex, I'm think something may reside in that.

Comment: So yeah, WMI works while the user is off, I'm guessing the user being logged in was for other win versions. I can run `wmic /node:%strIP% printer get /value` fine, but when I try to set the DriverName, it gives me the generic failure message. I could use the port number, but that will require more work, as the printers will have different ones, so I'd have to run `/value` to find the printer with the name lp1, save the portname to a variable and then run wmi again using the portname to set the driver.

Comment: I'd try `wmic path Win32_Printer` (note the class name `path Win32_Printer` instead of `printer` alias) as for my _feeling_ that `wmic` aliases may not treat the `set` verb duly. For printing double sided there is a read-only `Duplex` property in the `Win32_PrinterConfiguration` class:  if `TRUE`, printing is done on both sides. Not found any `wmi` setting how to do so along the long or short edge:(

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't particularly answer your actual question but as a solution for how I do this very same thing I thought I would give you what I threw together to update printer properties. I have not cleaned this up at all as I was porting it from my create printer function.

```
Function Set-SSPrinter {

Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        ValueFromPipeline=$True,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$ComputerName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$Name,
    [string]$PortName,
    [string]$DriverName,
    [string]$Comment,
    [string]$Location,
    [bool]$Shared,
    [string]$ShareName = $Name,
    [string]$PermissionSDDL,
    [string]$PrintProcessor,
    [string]$DataType,
    [bool]$RawOnly
    )

try {
    $modprinter = Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer -ComputerName $ComputerName | ?{$_.name -eq $Name}
    $modprinter.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = $true

        if($DriverName) {
            $modprinter.DriverName = $DriverName
        }
        if($PortName) {
            $modprinter.PortName = $PortName
        }
        if($Shared) {
            $modprinter.Shared = $Shared
        }
        if($ShareName) {
            $modprinter.ShareName = $ShareName
        }
        if($Location) {
            $modprinter.Location = $Location
        }
        if($Comment) {
            $modprinter.Comment = $Comment
        }
        if($Name) {
            $modprinter.DeviceID = $Name
        }
        if($PrintProcessor) {
            $modprinter.PrintProcessor = $PrintProcessor
           }
        if($DataType) {
            $modprinter.PrintJobDataType = $DataType
        }
        if($RawOnly) {
            $modprinter.RawOnly = $RawOnly  
           }

        $result = $modprinter.Put()

        if($PermissionSDDL) {
            $modprinter.SetSecurityDescriptor($objHelper.SDDLToWin32SD($PermissionSDDL).Descriptor) | Out-Null
        }
        $("Update Complete: " + $Name)
    } catch {
        $("Update Failed: " + $Name)
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message 
        $error.Clear()
    }

}
```

Unfortunately I use the printer name to figure out which device to modify on the remote machine. Your executing credentials from the powershell session you have open must have admin rights on the remote machine. if necessary do a runas different user on powershell.exe

Example usage:

```
Set-SSPrinter -ComputerName "10.210.20.100" -Name "TestPrinter" -DriverName "Lexmark Universal v2"
```

Comment: The issue I have is that you have a newer version of powershell, I do not.  If I had the latest version, which comes with a plethora of printer cmdlets, it'd be so much easier.  I'll keep this handy, should my employer accept to allow updating powershell.

Comment: I wrote the above because I too do not have the cmdlets you are talking of available on our sys admin win7 machines. You should be able to use this in powershell 2.0, the function is purely using WMI object. Try copy and pasting the function I have above into a powershell window, then forming your command based on my example. If it fails I would be curious to know what the error message is.

Comment: I have been trying that, both using the `-ComputerName` switch and without it using `Invoke-Command`.  My script does the same as yours, minus you seem to set more than one value, I only need one for now.  The one thing I noticed missing in mine is the `$modprinter.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = $true`. What does that do?  Same thing with `$modprinter.SetSecurityDescriptor($objHelper.SDDLToWin32SD($PermissionSDDL).Descriptor) | Out-Null`, not sure what that does. I'll update my question with my current PS1 script.

Comment: I updated the question.  As before, the script does not work when the pc is logged off.  I RDP in, as soon as I can see the desktop, I run it again, and no generic failure message. I also saw in a topic elsewhere about the differences between `.Put_` and `.Put()`. With `.Put_` I don't get a failure message, it seems to finish, but when I logged in to the pc and checked the driver settings, they were not actually updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic /node:servername /user:username /password:password path win32_something call methodname
```

Is how to do it.

Things with users are best done with logon scripts because that is how windows is designed.

Comment: So it is not possible to do so remotely without an initial login?  Whether I use `wmic /node:%strIP% printer where DeviceID="lp1" set DriverName="Lexmark Universal v2"` in command prompt or `$lp1 = Get-WMIObject -Credential $Cred -ComputerName $PCNm -Query "SELECT * from Win32_Printer Where DeviceID='lp1'";
$lp1.DriverName = "Lexmark Universal v2";
$lp1.Put()` in Powershell, I get generic failures. As soon as RDP in and login, it works fine; ie no more generic failure.

Comment: Additionally I find the printers in the registry, `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers\lp1"`, but when I change the driverName there, it does not update when I go into Devices and Printers to check; ie driver is still something else.