# How can I remotely login a user in Windows 7 from powershell, cmd or a VBScript?

Tags: windows, powershell, authentication, wmi

I've been trying to use WMI to remotely update printer drivers on a domain. I've been getting generic failure messages when I try to run it remotely if no user is logged in.  Once I, admin, log in, I run my script and it works fine.  I've exhausted all ways in PS; invoke-command, enter-pssession, get-wmiobject,etc. What I want to do now is run a script that logs me in remotely without actually having to RDP in or be there in person. Company security policy has the pc log users off automatically after 30mins, so all I need to do is either login remotely, or sendkeys to it; ctrl+alt+del, followed by my username, then tab once, then type in the password and then press enter.  Once I'm logged in, I can have the script run the wmi command to update the driver. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues automating printer driver update (printer settings) and printer preferences in Win7, using a PS,cmd,vbs,etc script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570390/issues-automating-printer-driver-update-printer-settings-and-printer-preferenc)

Comment: This is separate. While relevant, I'm asking something different. I'm trying to send keys to a remote pc, that I know is logged off.  I've tried using sendwait, sendkeys and send-keys, from .net, vbs and WASP respectively.   Both locally and remotely, I cannot do ctrl+alt+del.  I've tested locally Ctrl+Shift+Del, which in web browsers opens the option to clear browsing history. I use `send-keys "^(+{DEL})"` to clear the browsing history; ie it works. When I try `send-keys "^(%{DEL})"`, it does nothing. The PC is on a domain and when I try VBS or .net, I get access denied, though I'm an admin.

Comment: Don't use `SendKeys` to automate RDP logins. Ever. What actual problem are you trying to solve that isn't solved by the answers to your previous (very similar-looking) question?

Comment: Remote wmi seems to not work when no domain user is logged on.  I RDP in and log in as an admin, then test run the same remote wmi script and it works then. If I have to rdp in, I might as well just do it manually, but I want to automate it as there are thousands of pcs that need updating.